# Как прочитать файл (json) из самописного Chrome расширения?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension

Написал расширение для Chrome. Как загрузить файл json и вывести данные из него в окно расширения?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для реализации данной задачи, если данные в JSON файле всегда будут меняться, вам надо создать файл на каком то сервере (хостинг) и написать скрипт в расширении, который будет обращаться к данному файлу и получать данные.